# Given a jump function, how to make sure a robot can jump one stair without using any loop and variable?

Tags: algorithm

I have a weird interview question. That is: given a jump function, a robot can either jump by 1 step if jump function returns true or fall by 1 step if it returns false, suppose the probability is 50-50.

How to write a program to promise that the robot can jump one step without using any loop and variables.

Hint: Write a recursive question to fix it.

I still don't know how to deal with it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What approach have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

If your `jump()` function has a 50-50 chance of jumping up one step or falling down one step, then you need to recursively call the function two more times when it falls.

```
define jump_up():
    if !jump():
        jump_up()
        jump_up()
```

This will do nothing in the base case, because the `jump()` succeeded, but for every time it falls one step, it will be guaranteed to jump up two, always ending up one step higher than it started.

This solution assumes an infinite staircase, since you could (theoretically) fall an infinite number of times before finally succeeding.

Comment: Are you playing the [St. Petersburg game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) with the function call stack?! You are awesome!

Comment: The more precise formulation would be: "the expected height of the call stack is infinite".

Comment: Note that the probability of jumping forward doesn't affect the correctness of this algorithm, just the expected size of the call tree.